# Regular expressions doubts

Tags: regex, perl

I have a few doubts that I have not managed to clear up by research and am hoping for some help.

1) What does the `m` do, and what do the `/ /` before the m and at the end do?
        $var  =~  m/[^0-9]+/

2) `/[^0-9]+/` Which of the following lines does this regex match?

```
     A) `123`

     B) `4`

     C) `I see 5 dogs`

     D) `I see five dogs`
```

My answer to 2): It matches `C` and `D`, and not `A` and `B` because there is no character or wold that does not contain `0-9`.

Comment: Actually `/[^0-9]+/` would match `I` `see` `dogs` in option **C**. More about `m` [here](https://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/PERL/node83.html).

Comment: It wouldn't, without a `g` modifier.

Comment: This is a basic question, but I don't see why it should have 7 downvotes and 4 close votes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`m//` is the match operator. `//` are delimiters of the regex that you are mathing. If you are using default delimiters (`//`), then you can skip specifying `m` at the beginning.

If you want to use some other charaters as delimiters, for example `!`, then `m` is required: `m!/some/string/with/slashes!`.